# URL Redirect/Rewrite when opened from Mobile Browser

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

We are working on two website, where one is webapplication and another is mobile application.

So my requirement is to create a redirection url to redirect from webapplication to mobile application for mobile users but the folder or structure is different.

For Web Application it's 
http://testrequest.com/home/Account/
and for mobile it should be http://m.testresponce.com/mforyourhome/Account.aspx

Please can someone help me on using the URL Rewrite.

Edited:- Working on IIS7

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: How about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170965/redirect-to-mobile-default-page-by-urlrewrite-module-on-iis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` condition to do this.
Applied to your case, it would be as follow:

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^home/Account/$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.testresponce.com/mforyourhome/Account.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

It will match exactely `home/Account/` and if the user is browsing from a mobile device, he/she will be redirected to `http://m.testresponce.com/mforyourhome/Account.aspx`

**Important**

Apply this rule on `http://testrequest.com/` only (or at least avoid being stuck in an infinite redirect).
[User agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) are never 100% reliable (since they can be changed)

Source: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx

Comment: How about this question just redirect to different page not site, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170965/redirect-to-mobile-default-page-by-urlrewrite-module-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

To block redirect when return from your mobile site:

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^home/Account/$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="http://m.testresponce.com(.*)" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT} {HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent} {HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.testresponce.com/mforyourhome/Account.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```