# URL rewrite and Re-direct or Classic ASP script to redirect to a mobile site

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup a mobile re-direction script in classic ASP that detects the HTTP request and if its mobile, it will redirect the request to a mobile version of that page

so if this link opened from a mobile device:

http://www.example.com/about.asp it would re-direct to http://m.example.com/about.asp

most of the script i have tried they all to a re-direct to the mobile site home page, but I need to have it re-direct to a page level.

if this is doable in IIS7.5 i'm all for it too.

I got this to work with a help,

right now i have an issue, I have few folders which I need to block them from re-directing. i have piece of code, the folders are NOT being re-directed which is okay but when I access any other pages it goes to a homepage m.example.com....not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```
 <rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(example1|example2|exaple3)/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?!.*ipad).*(midp|mobile|phone).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Using IIS 7.5, you could go with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524467/url-redirect-rewrite-when-opened-from-mobile-browser/15533228#15533228

Comment: this one do a redirect to a specific page, i need something that will redirect all the pages.

Comment: Following your edit, you write `when I access any other pages it goes to a homepage m.example.com`, isn't this behavior the one expected??

Comment: no if i access mydomain.com/about.asp should go to m.mydomain.com/about.asp

Comment: So if you go to `mydomain.com/about.asp` you are redirected to `m.mydomain.com`, right? (if this is the case, I agree this is wrong since it should go to `m.mydomain.com/about.asp`)

Comment: your right!  it should go to m.mydomain.com/about.asp

Comment: Ok, I am a bit short on idea here...can you try to change the pattern to `url="^example1|example2|exaple3/?"` (removing the parenthesis)?

Comment: yeah i tried few things including removing paranthesis didnt work...

Comment: Can you use the failed request tracing tool to see why the back reference is empty?

Comment: checked, there was no error.

Comment: And the backreference is empty? Can you post the xml somewhere (pastebin)?

Comment: ive recycled the apppool too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IIS 7.5, you could use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

`url="^.*$"` will match any url and redirect to `http://m.example.com` happening the requested path if the conditions are met.

If you want to NOT apply this rule to the iPad, we will assume that the iPad user agent is as following (the important part will be that the word `iPad` is in it):

> Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314
>   Safari/531.21.10

(Source: [What is the iPad user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent))

Then you can modify the rule to this:

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?!.*ipad).*(midp|mobile|phone).*$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Where `pattern="^(?!.*ipad).*(midp|mobile|phone).*$"` will match `midp|mobile|phone` only if `ipad` is not present. (the pattern is, by default, not case sensitive)

Comment: this worked just great, how do I limit ipad users from re-directing i dont want Ipad users to redirect, is it possible with the URLrewrite?

Comment: I am testing something and will update my answer if I find a solution!

Comment: hey thanks for your code but it didnt work, it re-directed to the mobile version.

Comment: What if you use `pattern="^(?!.*ipad).*(midp|mobile|phone).*$"` on all the inputs to test? Can you find the user agent of your ipad browser?

Comment: As a test, what if you keep only one condition: `<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?!.*ipad).*(midp|mobile|phone).*$" />`?

Comment: Thanks this worked, quick question: can I do this with specific folders too? like NOT to have them re-directed within the same rule? like an example folder /example/

Comment: Not sure I understand your question :)

Comment: sorry my bad, so they way I have it setup with your help is to re-direct all the pages and etc to a mobile version, so what if i have a folder called http://www.example.com/example/ and i DON'T want to have that folder re-directed to a mobile version, can I put a block within the same rule? hope this makes more sense.

Comment: In this case, simply change `<match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="true" />` to `<match url="^example/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />`. So if the requested path starts with `example` or `example/`, the rule won't be triggered.

Comment: i see makes sense, and what if i have multiple folders?

Comment: Then you can use the `|` to separate the different folders. For example: `<match url="^(blog|about|home)/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />` would match any of the 3 words blog, about or home

Comment: Hi, sorry i one issue with outbound rewrite...do need to set it within the same config file?

Comment: hi there's an issue with this piece, it wont stop the re-direct it just goes to m.example.com homepage `code`<match url="^(blog|about|home)/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />`code`

Comment: What is the full configuration? If it is a different problem, it may be worth asking a new question :)

Comment: the configuration is the same as it was discussed few days ago, when i added the folder to <match url="^example/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" /> it did't stop the re-direct it goes to the mobile homepage. m.example.com

Comment: i dont think i need to ask a new questions? :) do I?

Comment: What url are you trying to reach? Because you have the `negate="true"` so it means whatever url not starting with `example` will trigger the rule!

Comment: im trying to reach this URL /example/ - if this  URL is accessed DO NOT redirect.

Comment: or even any other folder i get redirected to the homepage again.

Comment: That is weird if `http://yourwebserver/example` triggers the rule. Are you sure your browser hasn't cached the redirect (when it's a 301 permanent, some browsers do it). If not, can you use the [`failed request tracing tool`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see where it gets triggered?

Comment: I cleared the Cache. I used this code below the folders are not being re-directed which is good, but when i access everything else it goes to the mobile homepage<match url="^(example|example2|example3)/?" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />

Comment: I don't get it :) This is the goal here no? If not, please edit your question with the full rule and problem, it will be easier than in the comments.