# Recognize mobile devices and redirect them to subdomain from iis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I would like to recognize mobile devices accessing my website and based on that detection to redirect them to my `mobile.mywebsite.com`.

Is there any way to that using IIS RewriteRule not entering into current desktop website? If so, please share details. I have installed IIS Remote Manager and my hosting is shared one (winhost) if that is significant at all.

Update
I've found this pattern which I think? should work for me

```
<rule name="Mobile Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://m.mywebsite.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Should I put this using AddNewRule in IIS Remote Manager and if so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Redirect/Rewrite when opened from Mobile Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524467/url-redirect-rewrite-when-opened-from-mobile-browser)

Comment: `Should I put this using AddNewRule in IIS Remote Manager and if so how?`. You could, but it is simpler to just paste the rule XML you have into the `<configuration><system.webServer><rewrite><rules>` section of the the root `web.config` file of your MVC application.

Comment: ok, can you please post that as an answer.