# Redirect to mobile default page by UrlRewrite module on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Suppose there are two designed pages, one for desktop named `mobile.html` and the other one is `desktop.html`,
by below `UrlRewrite` I am able to redirect user to `mobile.html`

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="MobileRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/mobile.html" />
            </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it trapped in Too Many Request

> yourSite redirected you too many times.

it is clear that is because of that `rule`, it will redirected to `mobile.html` with no problem but by getting `mobile.html` that action occurred again, it will dropped in loop redirection.
also by adding `<add input="{url}" negate="true" pattern="mobile.html"/>` it is not working.

Comment: Do you only want to apply this rule to `mobile.html` and `desktop.html` or is it a site wide rule?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, I just want to apply this to `mobile` and `desktop` default pages

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Add another condition that excludes the mobile.html url.

```
<rule name="MobileRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" />
    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/mobile.html$" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/mobile.html" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Did you try another browser? The redirect can be stuck in the browser cache or something.

Comment: Yes, Since I have very challenged with cache, cleared it completely, tested in `incognito`, tested on cell phone , unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Why it trapped in loop redirection?, I think when it redirect to `mobile.html` that `MobileRedirect` occurred again, for this reason it cached in infinite redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want mobile users who land on `desktop.html` to be redirected to `mobile.html` and desktop users who land on `mobile.html` to be redirected to `desktop.html`. That would require 2 rules as follow:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="MobileRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="desktop.html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/mobile.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="DesktopRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="mobile.html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone|ipad" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/desktop.html" />
            </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Note that this 2 rules rely on [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) which are never 100% reliable (since they can be changed).